# make an array in wordpress cusmization api?

Tags: php, javascript, theme-customizer, array

i'm trying to make an array in wordpress customize.php 
i do used wp_localize_script in function.php as follow

```
    function mytheme_scripts() {

    wp_register_script('scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/scripts.js', 'jquery');

    $my_array = array( 'zoom' => get_theme_mod('zoom'), 'letter-spacing' => 'letter-spacing', 'rotate'  => 'rotate', 'left' => 'left' );
    wp_localize_script( 'scripts', 'effect', $my_array );

    wp_enqueue_script('scripts');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_scripts' );
```

in scripts.js im trying to change the effect using this

```
scrollorama.animate('.para-welcome',{
    delay: 200, duration: 300, property:'var para = effect.zoom;', start:0
});
```

my settings and controls are

```
        $wp_customize->add_setting( 'parallax_effect' , array(
        'default'     => 'zoom',
        'transport'   => 'postMessage',
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_control( 'parallax_effect', array(
        'label' => 'Parallax effect',
        'section'   => 'mytheme_welcome',
        'settings'  => 'parallax_effect',
        'type'      => 'select',
        'choices'    => array(
            'zoom' => 'zoom',
            'letter-spacing' => 'letter-spacing',
            'rotate' => 'rotate',
            'left' => 'left',
        ) 
    ) );
```

but it's not working yet i used all solutions i found but no changes 
any way i need to add select menu to change parallax effects of any section
can any one help please

Comment: If you localized $my_array as 'effect' ... then you would access it by using effect.zoom

Comment: i did but still not working

Comment: The only place you are using it in your script is as a string, and not as an array/obj

Comment: thats what i'm asking about how to change property:'var para = effect.zoom;' to select the option i use in menu options ?

Comment: I am not sure why you are declaring a variable inside property. Just use ... property:effect.zoom, ...

Comment: no change it shows the effect name inspect of changing the property value

Comment: Are you asking about the 'start' and 'end' value? I only see names in your $wp_customize, and your array only has property names. You will need to pass the property values to your arrays too.

Comment: that what i'm asking about ho to pass values from array to property in scripts.js?

Comment: Is it? How am I supposed to know? The title of your post is "make an array in wordpress cusmization api". There's no question mark in your post. Please, clarify exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: OK thanks and sorry for missing question mark mistake ^_^

Answer (score 0):

So there's 2 Customizer specific hooks depends on what exactly you're trying to do.

The `customize_controls_enqueue_scripts` is exactly like `wp_enqueue_scripts` but it enqueues in the control panel ( left side ) frame. I suggest requiring `customize-controls` scripts to make sure your script has access to them:

```
function theme_customizer_control_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'scirpt-slug', $scirpt_url, array( 'jquery', 'customize-controls' ), false, true );
}
add_action( 'customize_controls_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_customizer_control_scripts' );
```

- [The Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/customize_controls_enqueue_scripts) - `customize_controls_enqueue_scripts`
- [Dev Resources](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/customize_controls_enqueue_scripts/)

The 2nd is `customize_preview_init` which is where you'll be able to modify your customizer preview panel as controls change:

```
function theme_customizer_preview_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'scirpt-slug', $scirpt_url, array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
}
add_action( 'customize_preview_init', 'theme_customizer_preview_scripts' );
```

- [The Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/customize_preview_init) - `customize_preview_init`
- [Dev Resources](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/customize_preview_init/)

---

If you're trying to change elements on the fly from controls to previewer you would need to enqueue the following script / add the following code to the previewer side of things. Once enqueued there you should have access to the `wp.customize` object and can use jQuery as normal:

```
jQuery( window ).ready( function( $ ) {

    // WP Customize Manager JS Object
    var customizer = wp.customize;

    // Assign things by the Customize Control ID
    customizer( 'parallax_effect', function( control ) {

        // Bind some kind of event
        control.bind( function( value ) {

            if( 'zoom' === value ) {
                // Do something
                $( 'body' ).addClass( value );
            }

        } );

        // This will set the initial state. It's very heavy
        // I do not recommend doing this for multiple controls
        // Or at all... But it exists so I'm adding it to this answer
        $( control ).trigger( 'change' );
    }

} );
```

Comment: and how can i pass the array value to javascript?

Comment: You could use [wp_localize_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/) to pass in your array of `get_theme_option()`s. Or you can get the field directly whenever it changes using the code I've edited above.